# Post Multiple Checkbox from Table To Database Using Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, checkbox

I've the problem to post my checkbox to database. Please help me...

Here is my view :

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type='hidden' name='userid[]' value='1'>
            <input type='text' name='username[]' value='username1'> 
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type='checkbox' name='as_admin[]' value=1>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type='hidden' name='userid[]' value='2'>
            <input type='text' name='username[]' value='username2'> 
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type='checkbox' name='as_admin[]' value=1>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This is my controller :

```
$this->Model_user->insert_user();
```

And this is my model :

```
function insert_user(){
    $user_count = count($this->input->post('userid'));
    $userid     = $this->input->post('userid');
    $username   = $this->input->post('username');
    $as_admin   = $this->input->post('as_admin');

    for ($i=0; $i < $user_count; $i++){
        $info_user = array(
            'user_id'   => $userid[$i],
            'user_name' => $username[$i],
            'as_admin'  => $as_admin[$i],
        );
        $this->db->insert($info_user);
    }
}
```

And the problem is when 'username2' mark as admin (second row checkbox checked), in the database will be like this :

```
|user_id|user_name|as_admin|
|   1   |username1|   1    |
|   2   |username2|   0    |
```

it should be like this :

```
|user_id|user_name|as_admin|
|   1   |username1|   0    |
|   2   |username2|   1    |
```

Does anyone now how to save those thing, Please...

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Are you checking both checkbox at the same time?

Comment: @d.coder Look like it is, use radio instead.

Comment: when I checked the second row, the checkbox value saved into first row

Comment: If not then you must use radio.

Comment: can not use radio, because both can be as admin

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this, in your view, use the user id as key for as_admin

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type='hidden' name='userid[]' value='1'>
            <input type='text' name='username[]' value='username1'> 
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type='checkbox' name='as_admin[1]' value=1>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type='hidden' name='userid[]' value='2'>
            <input type='text' name='username[]' value='username2'> 
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type='checkbox' name='as_admin[2]' value=1>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

in your model

```
function insert_user(){
    $user_count = count($this->input->post('userid'));
    $userid     = $this->input->post('userid');
    $username   = $this->input->post('username');
    $as_admin   = $this->input->post('as_admin');

    for ($i=0; $i < $user_count; $i++){
        $info_user = array(
            'user_id'   => $userid[$i],
            'user_name' => $username[$i],
            'as_admin'  => isset($as_admin[$userid[$i]]) ? 1 : 0,
        );
        $this->db->insert($info_user);
    }
}
```

You are having this problem because, want you check only 1 checkbox, only checked value will be passed, so if you count the $as_admin you will get only 1 out of 2 as_admin.

if you make admin the username2 only

then your post will be as below

```
Array
(
    [userid] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
        )

    [username] => Array
        (
            [0] => username1
            [1] => username2
        )

    [as_admin] => Array
        (
            [2] => 1
        )
)
```

Comment: It is not required to set indexes in checkbox name `as_admin[1]`. But, you have done so then are you sure your for loop will set `as_admin` properly? `isset($as_admin[$userid[$i]]) ? 1 : 0` Loop iterate from 0 to less than `$user_count` but `as_admin` indexes are not same.

Comment: I have update my answer you will get your answer from that. we are using the user id as key for as_admin

Comment: Ohh I completely missed that.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that unchecked checkboxes are not posted and it is possible that none of the boxes are checked. If something is checked you need a way to associate the checkbox with the userid. This answer requires the value of `userid[]` to be the `value` of the checkbox. So the html is changed to this.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type='hidden' name='userid[]' value='1'>
      <input type='text' name='username[]' value='username1'> 
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type='checkbox' name='as_admin[]' value=1>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type='hidden' name='userid[]' value='2'>
      <input type='text' name='username[]' value='username2'> 
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type='checkbox' name='as_admin[]' value=2>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Essentially, the controller function will set `$info_user['as_admin'] = 1` if a 'userid' is a value in $_POST['as_admin'] and will set `$info_user['as_admin'] = 0` if it is not.

Rather than make repeated calls to `$this->db->insert` this answer uses `$this->db->insert_batch`. The array `$data` is an array of `$info_user` arrays.

```
function insert_user()
{
    //get the all of $_POST from $this->input
    //eliminates multiple calls to $this->input
    $posted = $this->input->post();

    //It's possible that no "admin" boxes are checked, if none provide empty array
    $as_admin = isset($posted['as_admin']) ? $posted['as_admin'] : array();

    $data = array();
    if(isset($posted['userid']))
    {
        foreach($posted['userid'] as $key => $value)
        {
            $info_user = array(
                'user_id' => $value,
                'user_name' => $posted['username'][$key],
                'as_admin' => in_array($posted['userid'][$key], $as_admin) ? 1 : 0,
            );
            $data[] = $info_user;
        }
        $this->db->insert_batch('some_table', $data);
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried this one but it seems not work for the checkbox (or maybe I have the wrong code) but thanks anyway...I have learn much from your code about insert batch...

Comment: I tested this and it worked. One very important item to double check is that in each `<tr>` the value of the checkbox must be the same as the value of the hidden field. In other words, if `<input type='hidden' name='userid[]' value='2'>` then you must have `<input type='checkbox' name='as_admin[]' value=2>` in that table row.